# How to exclude files for unit test in vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have an issue in a file when I run unit test in vueJs, this file is located in the path "webapp/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js" do you know how to avoid this file when I run `npm run test:unit`? I tried to avoid this file using this in `sonar-project.properties`:

```
sonar.exclusions=webapp/node_modules/**,webapp/tests/unit/**,webapp/coverage/lcov-report/**,webapp/src/models/**,webapp/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js
sonar.coverage.exclusions=webapp/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js
```

and I tried to exclude It in the jest.config.js using this:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js'
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    'webapp/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js',
  ]
};
```

but both options didn't worked, do you know how can I archive this? thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your Jest configuration should use relative paths from your `jest.config.js` file. Adjust your `collectCoverageFrom` and `coveragePathIgnorePatterns` accordingly:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: '@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest',
  collectCoverage: true,
  collectCoverageFrom: [
    'src/**/*.{js,vue}',
    '!src/main.js',
    '!src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js',
  ],
  coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',
    'src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js',
  ]
};
```

and for sonar, adjust your paths in `sonar.exclusions` and `sonar.coverage.exclusions` based on the location of your `sonar-project.properties` file:

```
sonar.exclusions=**/node_modules/**,**/tests/unit/**,**/coverage/lcov-report/**,**/src/models/**,**/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js
sonar.coverage.exclusions=**/src/components/fileDownloader/downloaderFile.js
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your `jest.config.js` file, you can specify which files or directories you want to `exclude` from unit tests using the `testPathIgnorePatterns` configuration option.

```
module.exports = {
  // Other Jest configuration options...

  testPathIgnorePatterns: [
    '/node_modules/',  // Exclude files in the node_modules directory
    '/dist/',          // Exclude files in the dist directory
    '/some-directory/',// Exclude files in a specific directory
    'filenameToExclude\\.js', // Exclude a specific file by name
  ],
};
```

After configuring the exclusion patterns, when you run your unit tests using the `npm test` or `yarn test` command, `Jest` will exclude the specified files and directories from being considered for tests.